# Getting Build failed error on AWS SAM build

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, sam

I got build failed error when i run `sam build`

Error:
`PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {future==0.18.2(sdist), wrapt==1.12.1(sdist)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by running the `sam build --use-container` command.
I got the same problem and it's working for me.